# Excluding specific methods from Autofac AsWebApiAuthenticationFilterFor

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am trying to add authentication for all methods in a WebApi2 controller *except* for one health endpoint named Ping that exists on all controllers. I have the auth working properly, but I don't see a way to apply the exclusion.

I would like to do something like the Exclude() below:

```
      builder.Register(e => new MyCustomAuthFilter(
      e.Resolve<IInjectedService>(),
      e.Resolve<IAnotherService>()))
      .AsWebApiAuthenticationFilterFor<MyController>()
      .Exclude(Ping)
      .InstancePerRequest();
      builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no opt-out on a per-item basis at this moment. You basically have the ability to attach to the whole controller or to an individual action, but that's it.

There's a [long running issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/issues/17) where folks would like the ability to attach a single filter registration to multiple controllers. I raise that because it also means you can't just do this:

```
// Doesn't work, this isn't a thing
builder.RegisterType<Filter>()
       .AsWebApiAuthenticationFilterFor<Controller>(c => c.Get())
       .AsWebApiAuthenticationFilterFor<Controller>(c => c.Post());
```

That is, as it stands today you couldn't foreach over the methods you want to opt-in and just have that work.

There's also a [long-running issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/issues/9) to allow filters to be attached by predicate. If that was implemented, you could do something like this:

```
// Doesn't work, this isn't a thing
builder.RegisterType<Filter>()
       .AsWebApiAuthenticationFilterFor<Controller>(method => method.Name != "Delete");
```

Unfortunately, there's a ton of work to do, so without some help from the community [in the form of PRs or some additional project owners](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2018/04/02/autofac-looking-for-extension-owners/) you may not see these any time soon.

**The best option I could offer you without that is to separate your controller into two different classes** - the methods you want covered in one controller, the methods you don't in a different controller. Derive the two from a common base class to share logic.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I had a feeling this was going to be the case but it doesn't hurt to ask. I'll take a look at the issue you mention above. If I can be of assistance I will do so gladly.